# CF: How to get a caller IP or hostname?

Tags: server, coldfusion, httprequest

I have a CF application, let's call it aaa.com. It has a function: `aaa.com/file.cfm`. I need `file.cfm` to be called in an other application, let's call it `bbb.com`.

Within `file.cfm` I would like to check, where the call is coming from. I tried to get the IP with

```
CGI.REMOTE_ADDR
```

But this is giving me the user's IP address. How can I verify that the call is coming from `bbb.com`? Is there a better way?

All, that `bbb.com` gets is the link `aaa.com/file.cfm`

Comment: Do a <cfdump var="#cgi#"> and you will see all fields available. Note that this is based on sent request headers which means they can possibly be spoofed by the end user

Comment: I checked it. But there is nothing i can verify its coming form bbb.com

Comment: `REMOTE` is the client and `SERVER` is the host. Dump out `CGI` and you'll get your IP. Also, why does it need to be the IP address? You can't just hardcode it since it never changes?

Comment: What kind of a server are you running it on?

Comment: You might need to check HTTP headers for [Forwarded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded). Some webservers (e.g. IIS) and most proxies pass the origin via header only. The CGI scope in CF is just a naive collection, better use `getHttpRequestData()` to check on the request. Besides that: Is the request from `bbb.com` clientside (a visitor from this website) or serverside (request via HTTP client)?